# Need help using Loc to bin and replace numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with number values. I want to determine if the number in the column is above or below the number 30 and replace it with a 1 if its above and 0 if its below. I am currently using .loc but I can't seem to figure out the | annotation feature

```
    kraken = pd.read_csv(data_path + 'ITSM_Master_2020-10-05.csv')
    kraken.loc[[kraken['Incident_Duration']<30, 'high_or_low']=0 | 
    [kraken['Incident_Duration']>=30, 'high_or_low']=1]
```

something like that? I am putting the numbers into a column called high or low
Incident Duration is a large column with numbers ranging from 0-100 for example

```
  Incident Duration = [25,26,50,52,50,100,5]
```

Comment: Please include code to initialize an example `kraken`. As written, it seems that you expect us to write this out ourselves.

Comment: tried to add some more detail to help. Its more on the syntax I am messed up on

Comment: Since this is a question about pandas, that's the tag you should have. This is not related to jupyter, np, or uilocalnotification, so please remove those tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

1. Your syntax inside `loc`. You are passing a list with a dataframe and a string inside of it, I'm not even sure to be honest what's going on there. I'll show below how I usually work with `loc`, but perhaps you are not wrong I'm just not sure the source of your problem.
2. You don't need `|` between the two assignments.
3. Followed by 2. You should initiate the column 'high_or_low' before assigning values to it using `loc`. So let's initiate it with the values 0, and place 1 wherever needed by your condition.

Solution:

```py
kraken['high_or_low'] = 0
kraken.loc[kraken['Incident_Duration'] >= 30, 'high_or_low'] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `loc`. If you just do `kraken["Incident_Duration"] >= 30` you get a boolean series that tells you, for each row, whether the condition was met. So all that is left is to convert that to `0` or `1` and append the series as a column of your data frame. You have two options for that:

- One is to cast the series to int using pandas' `astype()` method:

```
kraken["high_or_low"] = (kraken["Incident_Duration"] >= 30).astype(int)
```

- The other option is to multiply by 1, which causes pandas to cast it to `int`:

```
kraken["high_or_low"] = (kraken["Incident_Duration"] >= 30) * 1
```